# Finding area in a bounded region

Tags: calculus, integration, graphing-functions

How would I solve the following problem?

> Sketch the region bounded by the graphs of $f(x)=x^2-4x$ and $-3x^2$ and then find the area of the region.

I have made a sketch for this question but what I am not sure how to do is find the area.

I have found the intersections $x=0$ and $x=1$

$x^2-4x=-3x^2$

$4x^2-4x=0$

$x=0,x=1$

$$f(x)=\int_0^1 x^2-4x-(-3x^2)(dx)$$

$$f(x)=\int_0^1 4x^2-4x(dx)$$

$$G(X)=\frac{4x^3}{3}-2x^2$$

So I did

$$A=\frac{4}{3}(1)-2(1)^2-0$$

$$A=\frac{-2}{3}$$

But how can an Area be negative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that on the interval $[0, 1]$, $-3x^2 > (x^2 - 4x)$.  So the "upper curve" we are interested in is $-3x^2$ and the lower curve $(x^2 - 4x)$.

Always subtract the curve that is UNDER, from the curve that is OVER.

So you need for your integrand to be $$\int_0^1 -3x^2 - (x^2 - 4x) \,dx$$

Otherwise, your work was fine! You found your bounds correctly, and you integrated and evaluated correctly, just wrong choice of the *order* of subtraction.

Comment: I see that makes sense but to tell which one is over and which one is under should I plug in a test point like f(1/4) and the greater one would the OVER one?

Comment: Test points are good. But one of the reasons your exercise asked you to sketch the graphs of the functions and area bounded by them was to help you visualize which is on top. Sometimes, two graphs might intersect at three points, where between the first two, one function is greater than the other, and between the second and third point, that reverses. (Think of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ over the interval $[0, \pi]$. So you might need to check a test point on each side of the points of intersection.

Comment: Yes, in this example, 1/4 would be a fine text point: the function that is OVER the other will evaluate greater than the other.

Comment: Ok that makes sense thanks.

Comment: @amWhy: Always helpful and instructive! +1

Answer (score 3):

When finding the area bounded by the two curves, make sure you're always integrating **top** minus **bottom**.  In this case, the $-3x^2$ is actually greater than $x^2 - 4x$.  Thus, your integral should be:
$$\int_0^1-3x^2-\left(x^2 - 4x\right)\;dx$$
That was the only error you made.

Comment: I see thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

Determine the  point of Intersect bounded by the  curve f(x) = x to the  power 4 and 2x to the power 2 and  g(x)= 2x to the power 2, (( i=(2) , (j) = 3,((( -3 is equal and less than x < 3)))

Comment: Pleas use [mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to improve the readability of your answer. This amounts often just to enclosing formulas between two dollar signs.

Comment: Besides, this question was already solved and the answer accepted years ago, so you should answer to it only if you think you have something new to contribute with.